# Output data in a single line to a csv file

Tags: python-3.x, cx-oracle

How can I output data from the database in a single line to a csv file? Now it looks like this:

```
ID
SN
CLASS_ID
```

and I need as:

```
ID SN CLASS_ID
```

My code so far:

```
path = "C:\IBSO\DOK\exercise_1.csv"
try:
    connection = cx_Oracle.connect("admin", "123", "localhost")
except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as err:
    print("Error auth", err)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("""
    SELECT * FROM Z#PRODUCT
    WHERE ROWNUM <=10
    """)
with open(path, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
     writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
     for column in cursor.description:
        writer.writerow(''.join(column[0]))
```

Comment: Where are you fetching the output of `cur.execute`? I can't seem to find `cur.fetchall()` in your code.

Comment: Firstly I want output column name

Answer (score 0):

You can use`pandas.read_sql(conn, query)` to read your SQL into a `pandas.DataFrame` and then save to file using `pandas.to_csv(path)`

so the code would be something like:

```
import pandas as pd 
path = "C:\IBSO\DOK\exercise_1.csv"
try:
    connection = cx_Oracle.connect("admin", "123", "localhost")
except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as err:
    print("Error auth", err)
query = """
        SELECT * FROM Z#PRODUCT
        WHERE ROWNUM <=10
        """
df = pd.read_sql(connection, query)
df.to_csv(path, index= False)
```

Theoretically, you could likely one-line it into: `pd.read_sql(connection, query).to_csv(path, index= False)` but I have not tested that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in

```
for column in cursor.description:
    writer.writerow(''.join(column[0]))
```

I assume that each `column` is a string, so for each `column` you write the results of joining, with the null string, the individual characters in the column name, e.g.:

```
In [58]: ''.join('asdfe')                                                                 
Out[58]: 'asdfe'
```

and using `writerow` then you put a single column name on an individual row.

What you want to do is to leave the work to `writerow` that is designed to put in the CSV the values contained in a, losely speaking, list:

```
with open(path, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
     writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ')

     writer.writerow(cursor.description)
     # other code where you process and output the query results
```